# Having issues running react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native

Since I've installed react-native-vector-icons, I've been fancing trouble trying to run the app on my android.

This is what it shows when I try the react-native run-android command:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:classpath'.
  >   Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\Pichau.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.71\descriptors\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.20\475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08\descriptor.bin
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run
CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:classpath'.
  >   Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\Pichau.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.71\descriptors\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.20\475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08\descriptor.bin
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Pichau\Desktop\PetCare-RN\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\Pichau\Desktop\PetCare-RN\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at C:\Users\Pichau\Desktop\PetCare-RN\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Pichau\Desktop\PetCare-RN\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

Comment: Did you run react-native link after installing the package?

Comment: What version of react-native are you using?  could you please log your package json?

Comment: I did run with react-native link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my package.json file
{
  "name": "petcare",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}